# interpretation of communities object returned by louvain() in R

Tags: r

I've started learning R, and trying to implement community detection in R using louvain() function, so I tried passing some random data to it and observing the result

code:

```
G <- matrix(c(1:10000), nrow = 100, ncol = 100, byrow = TRUE)
f <- louvain(G)
print(f)
```

output:

```
> G <- matrix(c(1:10000), nrow = 100, ncol = 100, byrow = TRUE)
> print(louvain(G))
$`community`
[1] 1 2 2 3 3 2 3 2 1 1 1 3 3 2 2 1 2 1 1 2 1 2 1 2 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 1 2 2 1 3 1
[38] 1 3 3 1 1 3 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 3 2 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 2 3 1 3 2 2 1 3 1 1 2 2 3
[75] 2 1 2 3 3 3 3 1 2 1 3 1 1 2 2 1 2 2 2 1 1 3 2 2 1 1

$Q
[1] 1.327019e-18
```

I know that $Q implies the maximum modularity reached at gamma = 1, I want to know what does the data in the community object which is printed implies. Also what does the arguement `M0` means i.e. what data should be passed to it. And how do I decide the value of arguement `gamma`.

Thanks.

Comment: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/NetworkToolbox/versions/1.1.2/topics/louvain

Comment: @jogo I have referred to the documentation but can't understand it hence I posted my question on stack

Comment: Then you can use the source: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/NetworkToolbox/versions/1.1.2/source line 2341